# Compare numerous figures and identify the similar ones

Tags: python, r, pattern-recognition, principal-components

I am working on pattern recognition program using R/python. What would be the best way to compare two or more figures and identify/recognize the similar or duplicate figures based on pattern recognition?

Comment: this question shows 0 effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of papers on the internet, we can try to get the idea how to extract and process feature in a fingerprint. For instance, http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS790Q/PaperPresentations/MinutiaeDetection.pdf

Then you can use whatever classifier you want such as support vector machine.

If you need more idea you can visit http://dermatoglyphics.org/11-basic-patterns-of-fingerprint/ to generalize